# How to test Dockerfile RUN and CMD?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to understand how Dockerfile's RUN and CMD works.

From: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

> The `RUN` instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top
>      of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed
>      image will be used for the next step in the `Dockerfile`.
>
> The main purpose of a `CMD` is to provide defaults for an executing container.

And just to test if the `RUN` and `CMD` commands are executed from my `Dockerfile`, I have

```
RUN touch "RUN.s.txt"
CMD touch "CMD.s.txt"
```

None of those command are executed, otherwise I'll see those two files created.
So what went wrong?

Comment: Can you show the output of `docker build` and `docker run`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not able to see your files, as your container dies when it creates the file.

Remember `CMD` execute the command when container started. so to check the created filed you need to change `CMD`.

```
FROM alpine
RUN touch "RUN.s.txt"
CMD touch "CMD.s.txt" && ls
```

`CMD` should be a long-running process to interact with the container, otherwise, the container will die as soon as it completes the execution of `touch file`.

with `CMD touch "CMD.s.txt" && ls` you will able to see created file previously with `RUN touch "RUN.s.txt"` and the file created by `CMD`.